# How to revoke delete votes?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete

fat finger [accidentally voted to delete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12571969/203657) - is there any way to revoke that vote?

As an aside: this happened because I had to downvote [the intended target (>10k only)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17939476/203657) and on reloading the page, it kind of "jumped" to the end, so the other was at the old location. Faintly seem to remember that a while ago the post location was "sticky" (aka: page automatically scrolled to the new location) - any change or just me remembering incorrectly?

Comment: No, delete votes have no undo.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, that's what I feared not finding any option anywhere - just: that vote is clearly wrong, so there should be some way to remove it

Comment: As a workaround, ask the OP of the post to delete the post then undelete right after. This will effectively cancel your delete vote.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ahh, yeah, remember that I was recently confused about a deleted delete vote :-) The downvote (it's not mine) will stick in that process, will it?

Comment: @kleopatra yep upvotes, downvotes, close votes (in case of a question) are all restored once it's undeleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In lieu of an undo/revoke, you could leave a comment stating that the click was completely innocent and unintentional. This will probably make the author feel a little better (though the down vote will still exist); but more importantly, might prevent any possible lemming / dog-piling where others might feel that since one person thought it should be deleted, they should too.

Comment: good idea, thanks :-) Yeah, the latter is what I'm most concerned about ...